# Not able to download all available data from Google Finance

Tags: python, pandas, google-api, google-finance, google-finance-api

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas_datareader.data as web

start = dt.datetime(2007,1,3)
end = dt.datetime(2017,10,30)

df = web.DataReader('XCSE:OMX Stockholm PI', 'google', start, end)
df.to_csv('C:/Users/Me/Documents/stockholmpi.csv')
print('done')
```

[Here is the chart of the data I'm trying to download](https://finance.google.com/finance?q=INDEXNASDAQ%3AOMXSPI&sq=INDEXNASDAQ%3AOMXSPI&sp=1&ei=H2_3WdC4HIb4swGa5LroDA). There should be data from 2003 according to the chart, however when I run the code above I only get data from November 1st 2016 to the October 27th 2017. Anyone have any idea why that is? I also get the exact same data no matter what dates I put in, whether 2016-2017 is included or not.

Comment: Is the returned data paginated?

Comment: No there is only one page in which all data is crammed into a single column.

Comment: Google has changed the url to the finance site:
Please check here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/394